# Find intersections of millions of arrays

Tags: arrays, algorithm, mapreduce, complexity-theory, intersection

So we have about 5 millions of arrays:

```
1) [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
2) [1, 4, 5]
3) [1, 4, 6, 9, 10]
4) ...
```

Pretty much. And we need to find intersection of each array with each other:

```
1st array intersection with 2nd: [1, 4, 5]; with 3rd: [1, 4, 6]...
2nd array intersection with 1st: [1, 4, 5]; with 3rd: [1, 4]...
3rd array intersection with 1st: [1, 4, 6]; with 2nd: [1, 4]...
```

So looks like the obvious algorithm is 2 nested loops which gives the complexity O(n*n) or something around that. Even if we store already calculated intersections (which might be impossible due to the memory limitations), it will give us something like ~O(n*n/2). It's a very rough complexity calculation, but anyway it will require 5 mlns * 5 mlns / 2 iterations. That's too much even if we put everything in RAM.

There's a trick however. We don't really need to know all intersections, we just need about 20,000 of the biggest. So, we may omit those arrays that contain just a few intersections (we may call them 'shared elements' as well):

```
1st array intersection with Nth, Mth, Kth... (20,000 of the largest intersections).
```

There are around 10 millions of possible elements, so every element of the array will be in range [1;10 mln].

We have to store strings as well as integers. But yes, we *may* just use indexes as integers, and perform replacement later. 10 millions of strings is not too much, that's why I'm using integers in the examples, not the strings. But actual *raw* data is strings: ['abcdef', 'abc', 'def', 'fghf'...] (as I wrote there are 10 millions unique strings).

Is there any way to do it faster? Especially if the data can't fit in memory (we may store strings as elements, not just integers)? Maybe some tricky map\reduce stuff... Or even GPU calculations. Any solution is welcome - ideas, algorithms, links, pieces of code. Thank you guys!

UPDATE. I found interesting posts which may help:

- http://www.dr-josiah.com/2012/03/why-we-didnt-use-bloom-filter.html
- http://www.dr-josiah.com/2011/09/improving-performance-by-1000x.html

Comment: How big are the values in the arrays? Are they as small as in your example?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "20,000 of the biggest"?

Comment: @MrSmith42, they can be strings as well, unfortunately. We can implement them using pure integers however (just as index) and replace those integers with the strings, later. But it will decrease the speed, finally, and I'd like to avoid this trick if possible. Anyway I'm just looking for the fastest solution, whichever comes.

Comment: What is the cardinality of the universe from which members of the sets are taken ?

Comment: The number of different values is important. One tactic that is often very fast is to replace each array by a structure that has a bit for each possible value, 0 if the array does not contain the value, 1 if it does. You can then do most of the work as logical AND operations in a single loop, with no conditional branches other than the loop continuation branch.

Comment: @JoelLee, yep that means 20k of the largest. We don't actually need to find intersections for all 5mlns-1 of the other arrays. We just can use 20k of those arrays that have the biggest intersection (the largest amount of shared elements). I don't know if this helps, however... We don't know if we find the largests until we calculate intersections for all the remaining arrays... But I just mention that in case if it decreases the complexity somehow.

Comment: Having strings in the arrays is a significant detail you should include in your question.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark, around 10 mlns possible elements

Comment: "20k of the largest" is not very descriptive.  Do you mean "the 20k largest"?  If not, tell us what you do mean.

Comment: 10 million possible elements is probably too many to store as @PatriciaShanahan suggested.  What's the average size of these arrays?  Are there duplicate arrays?  Are they sorted?

Comment: @AaronDufour, well sorry for my possible poor English (it's my third human language hehe). You're probably right, 20k of the largest ones. 20k of those arrays, which contain the maximum amoount of shared elements. In other words, we can use percentage matching. Like that: "for the first array, the most similar one is the array number 45 because those arrays are almost equal; after that, array number 87; after that, array number 13... (and this "after that" repeats 20k times).

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan, great idea, thank you. Need to perform some  calculations to determine if we have enough RAM in reality.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan's suggestion will cost `number of possible elements * number of arrays / 8` bytes, which in your case is almost 6 TB.  That's probably not going to work out.  Are you saying that you need the 20k largest intersections for each array?  That's an output of `100,000,000,000 = 10^11` arrays.

Comment: Do you need the 20k largest intersections for each array?  Or the 20k largest intersections overall?  For example, if you have a singleton array, do you want the 20k arrays that intersect it, or not bother since the intersection will have one element, and there are 20k intersections bigger?

Comment: @Teepeemm, 20k largest for each array, unfortunately. So these arrays will differ from each array.

Comment: An output of `10^11` arrays is going to be slow no matter the algorithm.  I think we need to back up a bit.  How are you getting the arrays to start with?  How are you using the answers that you get?  Is there some way that we can skip the intermediate step of finding the largest intersections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would be good to know more about the nature of the data, and then try to see if you can use a map reduce approach. Here is why:

I am thinking that you should start with a Count Sort O(n) of all your elements in all the arrays. That way you find the values with high frequency.

My theory is that your long intersections will have some common elements that show up in many arrays, and some other elements that show up less.

As you Count Sort, you'll store the address of each array where element X shows up.

Next step would be to start with the elements that show up the most and try to find out the intersections of the arrays that contain that element. I am not talking about looking only at intersections of the arrays that share the highest element, I am just lookig at reducing the O(NxN) process to a reasonable N value instead of millions.

This is why I think knowing a bit about the nature of the string elements may help. For example, if those arrays contain: City, Street, Race, Income, etc.., you could use that info a lot when walking the values that show up a lot.

Separately if you actually do have such Categories as City, Street, Income, I am thinking that you can take advantage of a standard Mapr-Reduce approach where you make that Tuple your key for the Reducer.

Comment: I think this makes a lot of sense! Sort the number of elements by their #occurrences. In a second run I would sort the arrays by the number of times their elements are in other arrays. For example say you have [A,B,C] then the value I would generate for this array is C = count(A)+count(B)+count(C). This allows you to sort all arrays. You can then run the O(N^2) algorithm on a subset of your dataset with a reasonable degree of accuracy.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Gabriel! By now, your answer seems to be the best. It works great for high-frequency elements. But we still need to find intersections for some 'exotic' elements that occur very rare, like that: [very_rare_elemen1, very_rare_element2...] And we still need to calculate intersections for those elements as well. However, I think I found the final solution based on your excellent idea of 'mapping' addresses of each element, pls look below (my original comment was too long and SO didn't let it).

Comment: So if we have a 'transformed' data, we can simply yield (Emit) each element of each result line, and do that for all the other lines. We simply yield all the other elements for the given one in the current line (and the other lines as well if we find the given element there), because we know that the other elements of that line do intersect with the given one. I hope I explained the idea, sorry for my English =) It will produce a huge output, but the pure complexity of the algorithm is not quadratic (overall is O(2N), I guess). We probably may combine the both solutions to get perfect results.

Comment: From a data-structure point of view to intersect array X and Y, if you store each arrays as a sorted list of integer. You could use very fast algorithm to compute the intersection. see http://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/06/05/fast-intersection-sorted-lists-sse/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of intersection, if we change the problem and say how many of each of these strings are in the other strings,  Aho–Corasick  algorithm may be come in handy. It is memory intensive. It has a pre -processing time of O(n). It has a running time of O(m) ( m is the pattern length). If there are too many matches then the performance reduces.
Since you need to find match of every string with every string, the complexity is going to be quadratic.

Comment: I think you should give us some details about this test, I think the results are highly relevant for this question. The keyword tree could be used to select the most occuring elements for example..